# How could I use map() in this code?

Tags: python

I have a string list

```
[str1, str2, str3.....]
```

and I also have a `def` to check the format of the strings, something like:

```
def CheckIP(strN):
    if(formatCorrect(strN)):
        return True
    return False
```

Now I want to check every string in list, and of course I can use for to check one by one. But could I use `map()` to make code more readable...?

Comment: also a quick note - in your `CheckIP` function, you don't really need the `if` statement, since you are just returning `True` if `formatCorrect` is True, and `False` if it is false. So you can just do `return formatCorrect(strN)`

Comment: Depending on the task consider using `filter()`

Comment: Thanks G. Meyer, good suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can map your list to your function and then use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to check if it returns `True` for every item:

```
if all(map(CheckIP, list_of_strings)):
    # All strings are good
```

Actually, it would be cleaner to just get rid of the `CheckIP` function and use `formatCorrect` directly:

```
if all(map(formatCorrect, list_of_strings)):
    # All strings are good
```

Also, as an added bonus, `all` uses lazy-evaluation.  Meaning, it only checks as many items as are necessary before returning a result.

---

Note however that a more common approach would be to use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) instead of `map`:

```
if all(formatCorrect(x) for x in list_of_strings):
```

In my opinion, generator expressions are always better than `map` because:

1. They are slightly more readable.
2. They are just as fast if not faster than using `map`.  Also, in Python 2.x, `map` creates a list object that is often unnecessary (wastes memory).  Only in Python 3.x does `map` use lazy-computation like a generator expression.
3. They are more powerful.  In addition to just mapping items to a function, generator expressions allow you to perform operations on each item as they are produced.  For example:

   ```
   sum(x * 2 for x in (1, 2, 3))
   ```
4. They are preferred by most Python programmers.  Keeping with convention is important when programming because it eases maintenance and makes your code more understandable.
5. There is talk of removing functions like `map`, `filter`, etc. from a future version of the language. Though this is not set in stone, it has come up many times in the Python community.

Of course, if you are a fan of functional programming, there isn't much chance you'll agree to points one and four. :)

Comment: What is best and why?

Comment: I think you already were saying this but to be more detailed - `all` only goes until it finds a value of `False`, so if one of the first few is the bad one, it will only have to iterate a couple times before finding it and will take much less time.

Comment: @G.Meyer - You're right, I should have been more clear on that.  It is a very a important point of using `all`.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

An example, how you could do:

```
in_str = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'not']
in_str2 = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']


def CheckIP(strN):
    # different than yours, just to show example.
    if 'str' in strN:       
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(all(map(CheckIP, in_str)))   # gives false
print(all(map(CheckIP, in_str2)))  # gives true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [str1, str2, str3.....]
answer = list(map(CheckIP, L))
```

`answer` is a list of booleans such that `answer[i]` is `CheckIP(L[i])`. If you want to further check if all of those values are True, you could use `all`:

```
all(answer)
```

This returns `True` if and only if all the values in `answer` are `True`. However, you may do this without listifying:

```
all(map(CheckIP, L)), as, in python3, `map` returns an iterator, not a list. This way, you don't waste space turning everything into a list. You also save on time, as the first `False` value makes `all` return `False`, stopping `map` from computing any remaining values
```